# Finding duplicates in 6 columns by excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have this code to check if a text is duplicated 6 times in 6 columns.
The columns are not sequential and selected by the user through combobox10 to combobox15.
Once the columns are identified, the code will check, if inside those 6 columns there is a common repeated text (must be repeated in 6 columns, not in 5 or less).
Each combobox will allow the user to select a different column in the sheet (sheet5), except the selection “Not Sure”. It will go to column “O”, which contain all the texts in other columns (without duplication).

The code is running fine for selections in combobox10, but giving the whole list for other comboboxes. How to correct the code?

```
Dim CoulPupil, CoulPulse, CoulBP, CoulRR, CoulTemp, CoulpH As String
Dim colmn1, colmn2, colmn3, colmn4, colmn5, colmn6 As Integer


' sending msg if nothing selected
If ComboBox10.value = "Not Sure" And ComboBox11.value = "Not Sure" And ComboBox12.value = "Not  Sure" And ComboBox13.value = "Not Sure" And ComboBox14.value = "Not Sure" And ComboBox15.value =  "Not Sure" Then
answer = MsgBox("Select some findings in the patients to show the list ", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Patient's data Missing")

End If

'if the user selected "Not Sure" the search will go to column O which contain the whole list
 'select appropriate column based on user selection
CoulPupil = IIf(ComboBox10.value = "Mydriasis", "A", IIf(ComboBox10.value = "Miosis", "B", "O"))
 CoulPulse = IIf(ComboBox11.value = "Tachycardia", "C", IIf(ComboBox11.value = "Bradycardia", "D", "O"))
 CoulBP = IIf(ComboBox12.value = "Hypertension", "E", IIf(ComboBox12.value = "Hypotension", "F", "O"))
CoulRR = IIf(ComboBox13.value = "Tachypnea", "G", IIf(ComboBox13.value = "Bradypnea", "H", "O"))
CoulTemp = IIf(ComboBox14.value = "Hyperthermia", "I", IIf(ComboBox14.value = "Hypothermia", "J", "O"))
CoulpH = IIf(ComboBox15.value = "Metabolic Acidosis", "K", IIf(ComboBox15.value = "Metabolic  Alkalosis", "L", _
IIf(ComboBox15.value = "Respiratory Acidosis", "M", IIf(ComboBox15.value = "Respiratory Alkalosis", "N", "O"))))


'convert column letter to number
colmn1 = Columns(CoulPupil).Column
colmn2 = Columns(CoulPulse).Column
colmn3 = Columns(CoulBP).Column
colmn4 = Columns(CoulRR).Column
colmn5 = Columns(CoulTemp).Column
colmn6 = Columns(CoulpH).Column

EntryForm.ListBox1.Clear

For i = 2 To 149

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range(Sheet5.Cells(2, colmn1), Sheet5.Cells(149, colmn1)), Sheet5.Cells(i, colmn1).value) > 0 _
And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range(Sheet5.Cells(2, colmn2), Sheet5.Cells(149, colmn2)), Sheet5.Cells(i, colmn1).value) > 0 _
And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range(Sheet5.Cells(2, colmn3), Sheet5.Cells(149, colmn3)), Sheet5.Cells(i, colmn1).value) > 0 _
And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range(Sheet5.Cells(2, colmn4), Sheet5.Cells(149, colmn4)), Sheet5.Cells(i, colmn1).value) > 0 _
And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range(Sheet5.Cells(2, colmn5), Sheet5.Cells(149, colmn5)), Sheet5.Cells(i, colmn1).value) > 0 _
And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range(Sheet5.Cells(2, colmn6), Sheet5.Cells(149, colmn6)), Sheet5.Cells(i, colmn1).value) > 0 _
Then

EntryForm.ListBox1.AddItem Sheet5.Cells(i, colmn1).value

End If

Next i


End Sub`
```

I tried this code but it is not accurate and giving column "O" list for combobox11 to combobox15 different selections

Comment: Side note: you have to `Dim` each variable individually in VBA. ex: `Dim colmn1 As Integer, colmn2 As Integer, ... `

Comment: "....a text is duplicated 6 times in 6 columns" do you mean the text has to appear six times in each of six columns for a total of 36 or once in each column for a total of six?

Comment: there are no duplicates inside any individual column. All values inside any individual column are unique. values can be repeated in two or three columns. I am searching for values that are repeated, duplicated in the 6 columns. so the list box will show only the value  which is found 6 times once in each column

Comment: How fill the comboBoxes with values? Maybe there are spaces before or after and and the comparisons are not satisfied...

Comment: There are no spaces in values